# Efficient solution to generating an array in PHP, which extracts unique data from one array, based on data from another

Tags: php, arrays

Writing in PHP, I have 2 arrays, each created from SQL queries.

The first query runs through a table that has multiple pieces of data that correspond to various quiz attempts. The table has a column for the user's Email, the activity ID (which represents a quiz attempt) and another 2 columns for data relating to the attempt (for example 'percentage achieved' or 'quiz ID'):

```
UserEmail   ActID   ActKey      ActMeta
joB@gm.com  2354    Percentage  98
joB@gm.com  2354    Quiz ID     4
boM@hm.com  4567    Percentage  65
boM@hm.com  4567    Quiz ID     7
```

Once queried, this first array (`$student_quiz_list`) stores the selected data in the form of

`[[UserEmail, ActID, ActKey, ActMeta], [UserEmail, ActID, ActKey, ActMeta], [UserEmail, ActID, ActKey, ActMeta]...]`

where each pair of sub-arrays corresponds to a single quiz attempt.

The second table that is queried has two columns that relate to the quizzes themselves. The first column is the Quiz ID and the second is the Quiz name.

```
Quiz ID      Quiz Name
   4         Hardware
   7         Logic
```

Once queried, this second array (`$quiz_list`) stores the selected data in the form of

```
[[ID, Name], [ID, Name]...]
```

What I need to do is create a 3rd array (from the 2 above) which holds the user's email and percentage score

`[email, percentage], [email, percentage]...]`

but with each sub-array corresponding to a unique actID (so basically the user's percentage in each quiz they attempted without duplicates) and (this is the challenging bit) **only for quizzes with certain ID** values, in this case, let's say quiz ID 4.

In PHP, what would be the most efficient solution to this? I continually create arrays with duplicates and cannot find a neat solution which provides the outcome desired.

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If all this data is coming from a database, why not write the queries such that the database performs all the heavy load?

Comment: Can a user have multiple quiz attempts with the same quiz id?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as the example and let me know.

```
   $student_quiz_list=array(
                array(
                    'UserEmail'=>'joB@gm.com','ActID'=>'2354','ActKey'=>'Percentage','ActMeta'=>'90',
                ),
                array(
                    'UserEmail'=>'joB@gm.com','ActID'=>'2354','ActKey'=>'QuizID','ActMeta'=>'4',
                ),
                array(
                    'UserEmail'=>'boM@hm.com','ActID'=>'4567','ActKey'=>'Percentage','ActMeta'=>'98',
                ),
                array(
                    'UserEmail'=>'boM@hm.com','ActID'=>'4567','ActKey'=>'QuizID','ActMeta'=>'7',
                ),
        );
        $final_array=array();
        foreach( $student_quiz_list as $row){
            if($row['ActKey']=='Percentage'){
              $final_array[]=array('UserEmail'=>$row['UserEmail'],
                                    'ActMeta'=>$row['ActMeta']
                                    ) ;
            }
            
        }
echo"<pre>"; print_r($final_array); echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi Xce, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post code in code tags and not as a screenshot as it is way easier to work with written code than an image.

Answer (score 0):

As commenter @Nico Haase suggested, you can do most of the logic in SQL. You didn't respond to my comment, so I suppose a user can have multiple attempts per quiz ID:

```
SELECT 
    UserEmail, 
    ActMeta 
FROM 
    your_table # replace with your table name
WHERE 
    ActKey = 'Percentage'
    AND ActID IN (
        # subselection with table alias
        SELECT 
            t2.ActID 
        FROM 
            your_table t2 # replace with your table name
        WHERE 
            t2.ActKey = 'Quiz ID' 
            AND t2.ActMeta = 2 # insert your desired quiz ID here
            AND t2.ActID = ActID
    )
```

(Query tested with MySQL/MariaDB)

**For the case that you cannot change the SQL part**, here is how you can process your data in PHP. But consider that a large dataset could exceed your server capabilities, so I would definitely recommend the solution above:

```
// Your sample data
$raw = [
    ['UserEmail' => 'joB@gm.com', 'ActID' => 2354, 'ActKey' => 'Percentage' , 'ActMeta' => 98], 
    ['UserEmail' => 'joB@gm.com', 'ActID' => 2354, 'ActKey' => 'Quiz ID', 'ActMeta' => 4], 
    ['UserEmail' => 'joB@gm.com', 'ActID' => 4567, 'ActKey' => 'Percentage' , 'ActMeta' => 65], 
    ['UserEmail' => 'joB@gm.com', 'ActID' => 4567, 'ActKey' => 'Quiz ID', 'ActMeta' => 7],   
];

// Extract the corresponding ActIDs for a QuizID
$quiz_id = 4;

$act_ids = array_column(
    array_filter(
        $raw,
        function($item) use ($quiz_id) {
            return $item['ActMeta'] == $quiz_id;
        }
    ),
    'ActID'
);

// Get the entries with ActKey 'Percentage' and an ActID present in the previously extracted set
$percentage_entries = array_filter(
    $raw,
    function($item) use ($act_ids) {
        return $item['ActKey'] === 'Percentage' && in_array($item['ActID'], $act_ids);
    }
);

// Map over the previous set to get the array into the final form 
$final = array_map(
    function($item) {
        return [$item['UserEmail'], $item['ActMeta']];   
    },
    $percentage_entries
);
```